# How to read line by line from stdin in python

Tags: python, stdin

Everyone knows how to count the characters from STDIN in C. However, when I tried to do that in python3, I find it is a puzzle.  (counter.py)

```
import sys
chrCounter = 0

for line in sys.stdin.readline():
    chrCounter += len(line)

print(chrCounter)
```

Then I try to test the program by

```
python3 counter.py < counter.py
```

The answer is only the length of the first line "import sys". In fact, the program ONLY read the first line from the standard input, and discard the rest of them.

It will be work if I take the place of sys.stdin.readline by sys.stdin.read()

```
import sys
print(len(sys.stdin.read()))
```

However, it is obviously, that the program is NOT suitable for a large input. Please give me a elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 49):

It's simpler:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    chrCounter += len(line)
```

The file-like object `sys.stdin` is automatically iterated over line by line; if you call `.readline()` on it, you only read the first line (and iterate over that character-by-character); if you call `read()`, then you'll read the entire input into a single string and iterate over *that*  character-by.character.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from Tim Pietzcker is IMHO the correct one. There are 2 similar ways of doing this. Using:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
```

and

```
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
```

The second option is closer to your original code. The difference between these two options is made clear by using e.g. the following modification of the for-loop body *and using keyboard for input*:

```
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    line_len = len(line)
    print('Last line was', line_len, 'chars long.')
    chrCounter += len(line)
```

If you use the first option (`for line in sys.stdin:`), then the lines are processed right after you hit enter.

If you use the second option (`for line in sys.stdin.readlines():`), then the whole file is first read, split into lines and only then they are processed.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `right after you hit enter`? I have a shell script which prints output line by line, and if I consume that using a pipe (`$ build.sh | my-python-file.py`) using this method `for line in sys.stdin:`, I do not get anything but the second option works fine.

Comment: It is already some time ago, since I answered this question. By "right after you hit enter" I meant "as soon as a newline character is read from standard input, i.e. once the iterator of the file is ready to provide next line to the calling code.

I am not able to say why the first approach does not work for your case, but the second one probably waits until all lines are produced and then pipes them to my-python-file.py where they are processed all at once.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will investigate why option 1 does not work for me and post here if any clue I get.

Answer (score 0):

If I just wanted a character count, I'd read in blocks at a time instead of lines at a time:

```
# 4096 chosen arbitrarily. Pick any other number you want to use.
print(sum(iter(lambda:len(sys.stdin.read(4096)), 0)))
```